# Calling an asynchronous function when navigating to a new tab

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios-camera

I'm trying to display James Montemagno's Media Picker immediately when a user navigates to one of my tabbed pages. I found a function called OnAppearing() that I tried overriding to create this result. Although it technically shows the camera immediately when I switch tabs, after I close out of the media picker I get an error saying "only one operation can be active at a time".

Here is how I'm trying to implement this feature:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        TakePhotoButton_Clicked();
    }


    async void TakePhotoButton_Clicked()
    {
        //Allows users to take pictures in the app
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            DisplayAlert("No Camera", "Camera is not available.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            //Sets the properties of the photo file 
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;
    }
```

I'm pretty new to all of this and I feel as if I'm making a technical error. I read this post https://damian.fyi/2016/07/06/only-one-operation-can-be-active-at-at-time/ about someone getting the same error. They claimed, "I finally realized that after taking the photo it was re-displaying the form, causing the appearing event to be fired again, and thus causing a new photo to be taken while the old one was being taken. Hence the crash."

However, I'm not catching how my code is causing this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use a `bool` variable to check if you have already taken a picture

```
bool first = true;

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   if (first) TakePhotoButton_Clicked();
}

async void TakePhotoButton_Clicked()
{
    first = false;

    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked to get rid of my error, but it will only display the media picker once. If I switch to a different tab and come back to the camera tab, the media picker will not display. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: if you really want to do that, a better approach might be to use the TabbedPage's CurrentPageChanged event to fire the picker instead of OnAppearing